# extjs desktop, can't save window position

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, resize

I need to save position and size of a window into a db table,
therefore:

on event "creation" --> save position and size

on event "move" --> save position

on event "resize" --> save size

on event "maximize" --> save "maximized",
but NOT position (0,0) and size (desktopSize)

- neccessary for that case:

  1. the user logs out and logs in
  2. pushing "restore"-Button
  3. window should shrink to size (and position) before maximized

This can only be achieved, if the old position and size remains in database.

Certain events start certain functions to store values via AJAX to db, as name implies:

*resize* : `saveSize()`
 
*move* : `savePosition()`
*maximize* : `saveMaximize()`
*restore* : `restoreWindow()`

But i don't know how to handle the events, because the events are not fired as I would "like" them to be fired. So the values i need to store are overwritten before i get the chance to get them. I logged the events:

(Case --> event(s))

Open window:
1. *move*
2. *resize*
3. *move*
**thats okay**

"click" Maximize:
1. *resize*
2. *move*
3. *maximize*
**position and size values are overwritten, but just needed to save flag "maximized":true**

"click" Restore:
1. *move*
2. *restore*
3. *resize*
**position is saved into db, before i can get the "old" values from db to restore**

moving window:
- *move*
**everything is fine**

How to handle this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got stuck in my own thoughts. Just forgot to ask
"how extjs is managing this: maximize and restore".

The state is stored in the window-object itself:

```
scope = win.events.maximize.listeners[0].scope;
(object) size = scope.restoreSize
[] position = scope.restorePos
```

Thus, the event "maximize" is fired last, so I can write the previous state into db, it's a bit dirty I think, because i don't know why extjs is firing events so often

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this manually, use component state handling instead: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/state/state.html

Comment: this is working only in a session! I am able to save the appropriate values, but the state changes BEFORE i can do this. So i need to handle the events, somehow...